# How can I remove duplicate data from GridView?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView which displays data from MySQL database
When I enter the code to display this information, everything works fine. However, after displaying the information, it continues to form duplicates of the same data.

Ex. The gridview would show the table

Customer ID Username Password

1           root     root

2           pie      root

3           apple    root

1           root     root

2           pie      root

3           apple    root

and ongoing..

Here is my code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string strConn = "server=localhost;user id=root;password=root;database=database";
            string sql = "SELECT entryform.username, entryform.email, entryform.password, entryform2.firstname, entryform2.surname, entryform2.phonenumber, entryform2.ext, entryform2.jobtitle, entryform2.company, entryform2.country, entryform2.provincestate, entryform2.city, entryform2.address1, entryform2.address2, entryform2.zip, entryform.customerid FROM entryform, entryform2";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(strConn);
            MySqlDataAdapter dA = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            conn.Open();
            dA.Fill(ds, "entryform,entryform2");
            dataGridView.DataSource = ds;
            dataGridView.DataBind();
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I'm still fairly new so I am not sure what I did wrong or what else I need to add to fix this error. If anyone can provide any tips, that would be great!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like a problem with JOIN in your SQL

Comment: use distinct in your query.

Comment: DISTINCT didnt help, everything still remains unchanged :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
dataGridView.Clear();
```

because maybe you are filling the dataGridView more than once! ;)

If is that you are getting duplicate values from the database, try this:

```
string sql = "SELECT DISTINCT entryform.username, entryform.email, entryform.password, entryform2.firstname, entryform2.surname, entryform2.phonenumber, entryform2.ext, entryform2.jobtitle, entryform2.company, entryform2.country, entryform2.provincestate, entryform2.city, entryform2.address1, entryform2.address2, entryform2.zip, entryform.customerid FROM entryform, entryform2";
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I might sound stupid for saying this, but where should I place the dataGridView.Clear();? I tried adding DISTINCT but the duplication still remains unchanged.

Comment: Try to place before the try ;) It´s only to clear the dataGridView of old data! 
I think that if with DISTINCT the duplicates still there, then the reason is because the duplicates don´t come form the database ;)

Comment: Great! I am glad to hear! If this worked, please check this question as correct, it will help more people ;)